# Sticky header columns do not match table columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a "persistent header" in a table according to this [example.](http://css-tricks.com/persistent-headers/)
The table itself is built with Bootstrap 2.3
My problem: the table header columns don't match the table columns if scrolled.

**Without** scrolling:
[image]

**With** scrolling a bit down:
[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="page-wrap">
<table class="table table-hover persist-area">
    <thead>
        <tr class="persist-header">
            <th></th>
            <th style="text-align:right"></th>
            <th style="text-align:right">one</th>
            <th style="text-align:right">two</th>
            <th style="text-align:right">three</th>
            <th style="text-align:right">four</th>
            <th style="text-align:right">five</th>
            <th style="text-align:right">six</th>
            <th style="text-align:right">seven</th>         
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:right">
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:right">
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:right">
                blublu
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:right">
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:right">
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:right">
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:right">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
*   { 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
}
h1 {
margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
p {
margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
#page-wrap { 
margin: 50px auto;
}
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
}
th { 
width: 200px;
}

/*this one is the replacement for scrolling*/
.floatingHeader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #E4205C;
}
```

JS:

```
function UpdateTableHeaders() {
$(".persist-area").each(function() {

    var el         = $(this),
    offset         = el.offset(),
    scrollTop      = $(window).scrollTop(),
    floatingHeader = $(".floatingHeader", this)

    if ((scrollTop > offset.top) && (scrollTop < offset.top + el.height())) {
        floatingHeader.css({
            "visibility": "visible"
        });
    } else {
        floatingHeader.css({
            "visibility": "hidden"
        });      
    };
});
}

$(function() {
var clonedHeaderRow;
$(".persist-area").each(function() {
    clonedHeaderRow = $(".persist-header", this);
    clonedHeaderRow
    .before(clonedHeaderRow.clone())
    .css("width", clonedHeaderRow.width())
    .addClass("floatingHeader");

});

$(window)
.scroll(UpdateTableHeaders)
.trigger("scroll");

});
```

[jsfiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6GvtH/)

Comment: Your JSFiddle appears to be working.. http://jsfiddle.net/6GvtH/1/ Could you provide the actual HTML you are using?

Comment: @JonathanCrowe Strange. It works in the JSFiddle, but in the real example the "blublus" are below "two". 
It's not Bootstrap (js or css) which causes the problem. Here is the full HTML: http://pastebin.com/emUW8r4q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) solved my question.

```
/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements */
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```